# how do you create a model from a csv file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app that takes in csv file and creates usl models, creates the plot and shows the model output:

## code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(usl)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("CSV Viewer"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
              accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
    fluidRow(
      column(6,radioButtons("xaxisGrp","X-Axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2"))),
      column(6,checkboxGroupInput("yaxisGrp","Y-axis:", c("1"="1","2"="2")))
    ),
    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                 c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
    radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                 c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"'),
    uiOutput("choose_columns")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot")),
      tabPanel("Data", tableOutput('contents'))
    )
  )
)


####server

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  dsnames <- c()

  data_set <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    data(specsdm91)
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(specsdm91)

    data_set<-read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, 
                       sep=input$sep, quote=input$quote)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({data_set()})

  observe({
    dsnames <- names(data_set())
    cb_options <- list()
    cb_options[ dsnames] <- dsnames
    updateRadioButtons(session, "xaxisGrp",
                       label = "X-Axis",
                       choices = cb_options,
                       selected = "")
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "yaxisGrp",
                             label = "Y-Axis",
                             choices = cb_options,
                             selected = "")
  })
  output$choose_dataset <- renderUI({
    selectInput("dataset", "Data set", as.list(data_sets))
  })
  output$plot = renderPlot(
    {
      df <- data_set()
      gp <- NULL
      if (!is.null(df)){
         ##I need to show the plot here from the model           
          plot(throughput ~ load, data=df)
          plot(usl.model, add=true)


        }
      }
      return(gp)
    }
  )
  output$choose_columns <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$dataset))
      return()
    colnames <- names(contents)
    checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Choose columns", 
                       choices  = colnames,
                       selected = colnames)
  }) 
}
```

## shinyApp(ui, server)

my csv file looks like this:

```
load    throughput
1   64.9
18  995.9
36  1652.4
72  1853.2
108 1828.9
144 1775
216 1702.2
```

===
When I do print on xv and yv, I get the variable names:

```
1] "load"
[1] "throughput"
```

I can also print the df:

```
  load throughput
1    1       64.9
2   18      995.9
3   36     1652.4
4   72     1853.2
5  108     1828.9
6  144     1775.0
7  216     1702.2
```

when I print this:

```
df$xv
```

I get

```
NULL
```

when I run the app, I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in <Anonymous>: invalid type (NULL) for variable 'df$xv'
Stack trace (innermost first):
    82: <Anonymous>
    81: eval
    80: eval
    79: plot.formula
    78: plot
    77: plot
    76: renderPlot [C:\shiny\file/ui.R#82]
    68: output$plot
     1: shiny::runAp
```

when I transform the df using melt function it works:

```
 mdf <- melt(df,id.vars=xv,measure.vars=yv)
          usl.model<-usl(value~load,data=mdf)
          plot(usl.model)
```

The problem is I need to be able to create the model using the variables taken from the csv file rather (xv and yv) than hard coding it like thie value and load. How can I can use variables xv and yv in creating my model and plotting. The variable names will change depending on what the columns names will be. I cannot use hard coded names in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't a 'minimal' example (lots of extra stuff in there) and doesn't work as provided (error in ln 78), and there's only a plot, nothing about a model.

That said, the problem is that you need to refer to the columns by the selected input; `input$xaxisGrp` for the X and `input$yaxisGrp` for the Y.

Changing your `renderPlot` to this will minimally achieve what you want

```
  output$plot = renderPlot({

df <- data_set()
df2 <- df[,c(input$xaxisGrp, input$yaxisGrp)]
if (!is.null(df)){
  ##I need to show the plot here from the model           
  #plot(throughput ~ load, data=df)
  plot(df2[,1], df2[,2])
  }
}
```

)

Though there are more extensible ways if you read up the Shiny docs.

Comment: I am very new to Shiny sorry for the post. Would you be able to take a look at this new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454567/unable-to-build-a-model-using-a-shiny-application when I click the plot tab, I am getting: need finite 'xlim' values error. Looks like x and y values are not getting populated.

Comment: Could you confirm whether you tried this answer for this question, before I move to another question, which looks to be a duplicate of this one?